# how do you sort an array with empty strings, NaN, numbers and infinity

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array that includes empty strings, numbers, "infinity", "-infinity", and "NaN". I am receiving all the values in form of strings, so sort is not working as expected when it comes to empty strings, inf and nan. Is there a way to customize my sort function both in ascending and descending order?

Comment: What is expected result? The anonymous function does not have a `.name`; how is the function called? Why would `String` `"inf"` be considered `Infinity`, or `String` `"Nan"` `NaN`?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just extend your current logic and assign the proper value to `result` based on the value of the string?

Comment: Why not using real globals like [Infinity](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Infinity), [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/NaN) instead of using strings ?

Comment: What is your expected order?

Comment: You need to explain how you want the empty string and NaN to fit into the ordering. Is the empty string equal to 0, or maybe greater than all negative numbers, but still less than 0, so you get a consistent sort? or maybe you want it to be less than even `-Infinity`. What about `NaN`? It's a bit absurd to call `NaN` negative, or positive, but almost as crazy to call it equal to `0`, so you need to define exactly what you mean by sorting all these things. What would your expected order be after sorting (using your strings) `["inf", "Nan", 0, "", 1, -1, "-inf"]`?

Comment: The expected result in ascending order - ["", "-inf", "Nan", "inf", -2, 0, 2, 3].  I would like to group string values like empty strings, + and - inf, nan together either at beginning or end based on sort order and sort then sort the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: according to your comment, `"" < "-inf" < "Nan" < "inf" <  ... < -1 < 0 < 1 < ...` . You can change this by modifying the `order` array.

Note this code will not work properly if the array contains elements that are not present in the `order` array. You can either set guards for that, or add other special elements (like `0`) to the `order` array.

Also note `NaN` and `Infinity` (not a string literals) are also a number in javascript. Using this code, they will be ordered next to numbers.

```
var basicCompare = function (a, b) {
    if (a > b) return 1;
    if (a < b) return -1;
    return 0;
}

var compare = function (a, b) {
    // 0 represents numbers.
    var order = ["", "-inf", "Nan", "inf", 0],
        orderOfNumber = order.indexOf(0),   
        orderOfA = typeof(a) === "number" ? orderOfNumber : order.indexOf(a),
        orderOfB = typeof(b) === "number" ? orderOfNumber : order.indexOf(b);

    if (orderOfA === orderOfNumber & orderOfB === orderOfNumber) {
        // They are both numbers, use regular comparison.
        return basicCompare(a, b);
    }

    // They are not both numbers, so use the axiomatic order.
    return basicCompare(orderOfA, orderOfB)
}

array.sort(compare);
```

Comment: The want to sort by string comparison. I do not want to parse this values. So my array is including strings and valid numbers. The order i am trying to acheive is arr =  ["", "-inf", "Nan", "inf", -2, 0, 2, 3].

Comment: I eddited the axiom to use that ordering. Please, read the code and feel free to ask me anything about it. I think it does what you mean.

Comment: Does this always sort "", inf's, nan as strings and group them followed by numbers based on the respective order?

Comment: Yes. I invite you to try with some sample arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object for the sort order and move the given items to the wanted position.

```js
var array = ["", 2, 3, 0, "inf", "-inf", "Nan", -1, -100000];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    var order = { "": -4, "-inf": -3, "Nan": -2, "inf": -1 };
    return (order[a] || 0) - (order[b] || 0) || a - b;
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Do you like my version? Thanks for your css :)?

Comment: no, the numbers are grouped with zero and then by the actual delta, please see edit with `-100000`.

Comment: @NinaScholz Ah, I see. Do you know if it is an issue to return `NaN` instead of `0` sometimes from the compare function, like you do if `a` and `b` are both "inf"?

Comment: the sort callback need a number smaller than zero, zero or greater than zero. what do you expect with `NaN` as value? i assume, `NaN` is interpreted as zero.